# What is the meaning of the notation C{...}, L{...} (specifically in Python, Twisted)?

Tags: python, twisted, notation

I'm learning Python's Twisted, and have to use their docstrings for help, as the documentation isn't the best. Fortunately the source code has good docstrings. For example I'm learning to use a `LoopingCall` ([class documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html), [source code](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.0.0/twisted/internet/task.py#L27)). But some of the notation confuses me. Having seen others' Java code, I get the following bits:

```
@ivar f: The function to call.
@ivar a: A tuple of arguments to pass the function.
@ivar kw: A dictionary of keyword arguments to pass to the function.
@ivar clock: A provider of
    L{twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime}.  The default is
    L{twisted.internet.reactor}. Feel free to set this to
    something else, but it probably ought to be set *before*
    calling L{start}.
...
@type _runAtStart: C{bool}
@ivar _runAtStart: A flag indicating whether the 'now' argument was passed
    to L{LoopingCall.start}.
```

I get how the `@label` is defining/documenting parameters for the class and its attributes. But does the `C{...}` specify the *class* or datatype? But then the first line of the class docstring is

> If C{f} returns a deferred, rescheduling will not take place until the deferred has fired. The result value is ignored.

so does that refer to the parameter `f` which is a function, and says what happens if that parameter returns a deferred?

And what in the world does the `L{...}` notation mean? It refers to `L{LoopingCall.start}`, and I know that's a method that can be called on the `LoopingCall`, but is there any additional significance to the `L{}` or just a computer-science-y way of saying *"this is a class method that we're referring to here"*?

Comment: That is special notation for generating the documentation (which is *automatically created from the docstrings*) - note that in the formatted documentation you link to the items with the braces are formatted differently. `L` appears to mean **l**ink and `C` **c**ode.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that's pretty cool! As I'm creating my first full-on application, I'll get to make a point to learn this for generating my own documentation.

Comment: No problem - turns out I made a pretty good guess! There are various other styles available - I like [the Google style with Sphinx-Napoleon](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html), as I think they're easier to read even without the formatting, but YMMV.